# Photoscore rhythm problems

Tags: software, rhythm, sibelius

Photoscore is having trouble importing Enough by Chris Tomlin into Sibelius for me. It is giving rhythm errors that look like this:

"This score contains bars that do not add up to the time signature they are highlighted with red dashed lines above and below it is strongly recommended that rhythm and key signatures are correct before opening PhotoScore files in other programs."

[image: rhythm]

and it is taking this music

[image: music1]

and doing this merge

[image: merged]

How do i fix the rhythm problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first upper note, the E (presuming that's treble clef) shouldn't have a dot.  The dot is redundant to the tie (that's a tie and not a slur, right?) to the following eighth note E.

Furthermore, if you really mean the pitches to have the durations they're lined up to have in the first example, that dotted quarter E not only shouldn't have a dot, it shouldn't be a quarter either.  It should be an eighth.

What your program is doing (possibly among other undesired things -- fix this and get back to us) is saying "dotted quarter?  Okey-doke!" and shoving all subsequent notes forward a beat to compensate.  Then not having enough pitches for all the syllables, making a hash of the lyrics.

Either that E needs to be an eighth to fit the bar, or you have to move some of those pitches and corresponding lyrics forward into the next bar.  Or, you know, as per [my previous answer on bar length](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/17210/10412), just make the bar longer. :)

Comment: While indeed the dotted crotchet should be an quaver here, I disagree that “the dot is redundant [with] the tie”. Dots and ties are perfectly compatible.

Comment: @Édouard oh, they certainly can be, but considering what the other two notes in that chord were doing duration-wise, it was redundant -- that eighth was already accounted for.